# how to compare arrays with NaN?

Tags: arrays, matlab, nan

The function ISEQUAL works fine with numbers and inf, but whenever a NaN appears in the array, it screws everything.
I am looking for a simple way to compare two arrays containing NaN's (which for me is good enough to say that NaN==NaN).
I was thinking of something like a bitwise comparison, but I don't know how to get to the exact bit representation of Matlab.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does [this](http://blogs.mathworks.com/seth/2009/02/04/how-do-i-test-for-nan-in-my-model/) help?

Comment: that elaborates more, thanks. 

However, I'm still looking for a way to perform a bitwise comparison between two arrays

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to know whether the *arrays* are equal,

```
tf = isequaln(A,B);
```

If you want to know whether the *elements* are equal (with NaN==NaN), you could do

```
nanA = isnan(A);
nanB = isnan(B);
tfByElement = A==B | nanA & nanB;
```

Comment: damn, I can't believe I missed that. Thanks. 
Does that cover any array (including cell arrays)?

Comment: @NoamG: Yes, `isequaln` covers any array, including cells, structs, and classes.